# get Version netCore csproj file powershell

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have net core project file. Version is stored in project.csproj file. I am using the following script to get the version string.

```
$Project = Resolve-Path ".\\source\\Project\\Project.csproj"
$xml = [Xml] (Get-Content $Project)
$version = [Version] ($xml.Project.PropertyGroup.Version)[0]
Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '$version']"
```

Here is the print out from execution in Windows Powershell ISE:

```
##teamcity[buildNumber '1.0.1']
```

However, it gave following error in TeamCity:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
[07:48:01][Step 4/16] At C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell340377043469883282.ps1:3 char
[07:48:01][Step 4/16] :59
[07:48:01][Step 4/16] + $version = [Version] ($xml.Project.PropertyGroup.Version)[ <<<< 0]
[07:48:01][Step 4/16]     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
[07:48:01][Step 4/16]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
[07:48:01][Step 4/16]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: [1] does it work without the space between the `[xml]` and the `(Get-Content $Project)`? [2] does `[xml]$content` return an XML object?

Comment: Are you sure the version **IS** set? The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784680/team-city-vs-2017-build-version) first checks it.

Comment: I tried @Lee_Dailey's methods. They didn't work.

Comment: @LotPings, the version is set in csproj file. I checked from the print out of csproj file.

Comment: @user3097695 - so ... [1] did either command produce a valid XML object? ///// [2] if the object is a valid XML object, is the property you seek in that object & at the expected location in that object? ///// [3] can you post the `Get-Content` from that file?

Comment: I get some errors in WindowsPowerShell ISE. [1]Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Version".
+ $version =  [Version] $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.Version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
 
version: 1.0.1
##teamcity[buildNumber '1.0.1      ']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the reason for my problem. In one of net core project, there are more than one PropertyGroup elements in this csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
  <AssemblyName>CoreApi</AssemblyName>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <PackageId>Project</PackageId>
  <Version>1.0.1</Version>
</PropertyGroup>

 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
 <TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
 <TreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors />
  <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\CoreApi.xml</DocumentationFile>
 <NoWarn>1701;1702;1705;NU1603</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In order to accommodate this, I have to use the following code

```
$Project = Resolve-Path ".\\source\\Project\\Project.csproj"
$xml = [Xml] (Get-Content $Project)
$propertyGroup = $xml.Project.PropertyGroup
if ($propertyGroup -is [array]) {
  $version = [version] $xml.Project.PropertyGroup[0].Version
  Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '$version']"
}else {
  $version = [version] $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.Version
  Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '$version']"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need run the commands in the folder containing the .csproj file, then run the following commands

$xml = [Xml] (Get-Content .\DEPLOY.Cachorro.Api.csproj) $version = [Version] $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.AssemblyVersion

You need to make sure if your version is within the AssemblyVersion or Version tag. I´m using AssemblyVersion
[image]

Then you can execute the command to know the value stored in your "version" variable

Write-Host "version: $version"

Take a look:
[image]